# Categorizing in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case, categories

So i have this table

```
id     |   object    |     type
--------------------------------
1      |   blue      |     color
1      |   burger    |     food
2      |   sandwich  |     food
2      |   red       |     color
2      |   coke      |     beverage 
3      |   sprite    |     beverage
3      |   coke      |     beverage
3      |   red       |     color
4      |   bacon     |     food
```

i have to create a select statement that will show a table with columns id, color, food and beverage. Arranged by ID with their designated things on it.

so my expected result is

```
id       |   color   |   food   |  beverage
-------------------------------------------
1        |   blue    |   burger |
2        |   red     | sandwich |   coke
3        |   red     |          |   sprite
3        |           |          |   coke
4        |           |  bacon   |
```

as of now i have this code

```
Select id as id,
Case When I.Type = 'color' Then I.Object End As color, 
Case When I.Type = 'food' Then I.Object End As food, 
Case When I.Type = 'beverage' Then I.Object End As beverage
From table I
order by id
```

but the problem with my code is it doesnt group by its ID so it creates multiple rows for every object.

TIA!

Comment: By what rule is "sprite" associated with "red" and "coke" associated with NULL for id=3? Why not the other way around? Is it random (so someone else solving the same problem may get a different solution, with both solutions equally valid)? Or are there additional rules?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a pivot query.  What is challenging about your problem is that, for a given `id` *and* `type`, there can be more than one `object` present.  To handle this, you can first do a `GROUP BY` query to CSV aggregate objects for a given type using `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'color'    THEN t.object ELSE NULL END) AS color,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'food'     THEN t.object ELSE NULL END) AS food,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'beverage' THEN t.object ELSE NULL END) AS beverage
FROM
(
    SELECT id,
           LISTAGG(object, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY object) AS object,
           type
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id, type
) t
GROUP BY t.id
```

The inner query first aggregates objects across both `id` *and* `type`, and the outer query is a simple pivot query as you might expect.

Here is a Fiddle which shows an almost identical query in MySQL (Oracle seems to be perpetually broken):

## SQLFiddle

Comment: it doesnt show all the objects the id has only 1 row per id is being initiated

Comment: can you show me how pivot query can work with my problem? @tim

Comment: @robing - `pivot` is not a solution to your problem. In a `pivot` operation, you should get only one row for each id; `pivot` is an aggregation operation, similar to `sum` and `count` - you get only one result for each group. Again: what you are trying to do is NOT a `pivot` operation.

Comment: @mathguy Always a pleasure to see you dropping comments on my answer.  If the OP can accept CSV objects, then there is nothing wrong with pivot.  As you said yourself, the suggested output is not relational, so this answer is one way to deal with this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I was actually answering the OP; the fact it was on your answer is an accident. Others suggested `pivot` as well; the OP chose to latch onto that in your answer, but it could have been elsewhere. My point to the OP was this: EITHER you want possibly more than one row for an id, OR you want a `pivot` solution; you can't have both.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - ...and (as often happens) my comment wasn't entirely correct either - this is, in a sense, a "pivot" kind of problem, but the grouping is not by id alone. But again, as a main point to these comments - this wasn't addressed to you, it was to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like the following:

```
with test(id, object, type) as
(
    select 1,'blue',    'color' from dual union all
    select 1,'burger',  'food' from dual union all
    select 2,'sandwich','food' from dual union all
    select 2,'red',     'color' from dual union all
    select 2,'coke',    'beverage' from dual union all 
    select 3,'sprite',  'beverage' from dual union all
    select 3,'coke',    'beverage' from dual union all
    select 3,'red',     'color' from dual union all
    select 4,'bacon',   'food' from dual
)
select id,
       max( case when type = 'color'    
              then object
              else null
            end
          ) as color,
       max( case when type = 'food'    
              then object
              else null
            end
          ) as food,
       max( case when type = 'beverage'    
              then object
              else null
            end
          ) as beverage
from (
        select id, object, type, row_number() over ( partition by id, type order by object) row_for_id
        from test
     )
group by id, row_for_id   
order by id, row_for_id
```

The inner query is the main part, where you handle the case of a single `id` with many objects of a type; you can modify the ordering by editing the `order by object`.
The external query can be re-written in different ways, for example with a `PIVOT`; i used the `MAX` hoping to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I have achieved using [pivot](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) clause

```
select id,object,type from yourtable
pivot
(
     LISTAGG(object, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY object)
     for type IN
               (
                  'color'  AS "color",
                  'food'   AS "food",
                  'beverage' AS "beverage"
               )
)
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Robin: My comment to you (under Tim Biegeleisen's answer) is partially incorrect. There IS a pivot-based solution; however, the "groups" are not by id, but instead they are by id AND rank within your three "categories". For this solution (or ANY solution that does not use dynamic SQL) to work, it is necessary that all the "types" (and their names) be known beforehand, and they must be hardcoded in the SQL query.

NOTE: In this solution, I assumed that for each id, the "objects" within the same "type" are associated to each other based on their alphabetical order (so, for example, for id = 3, "coke" is associated with "red" and "sprite" is associated with NULL, unlike your sample output). I asked you about that right below your Question - if there are additional rules you did not share with us, requiring a different pairing of objects of different types, it may or may not be possible to adapt the solution to meet those additional rules.

EDIT: On closer look, this is pretty much what Aleksej provided, without using the explicit `pivot` syntax. His solution has the advantage that it would work in older versions of Oracle (before 11.1 where `pivot` first became available).

QUERY (including test data in the first CTE):

```
with
     inputs ( id, object, type ) as (
       select 1, 'blue'     , 'color'    from dual union all
       select 1, 'burger'   , 'food'     from dual union all
       select 2, 'sandwich' , 'food'     from dual union all
       select 2, 'red'      , 'color'    from dual union all
       select 2, 'coke'     , 'beverage' from dual union all
       select 3, 'sprite'   , 'beverage' from dual union all
       select 3, 'coke'     , 'beverage' from dual union all
       select 3, 'red'      , 'color'    from dual union all
       select 4, 'bacon'    , 'food'     from dual 
     ),
     r ( id, object, type, rn ) as (
       select id, object, type, row_number() over (partition by id, type order by object)
       from   inputs
     )
select id, color, food, beverage
from   r
  pivot ( max(object) for type in ( 'color'    as color, 'food' as food, 
                                    'beverage' as beverage))
order by id, rn
;
```

OUTPUT:

```
  ID COLOR    FOOD     BEVERAGE
---- -------- -------- --------
   1 blue     burger
   2 red      sandwich coke
   3 red               coke
   3                   sprite
   4          bacon
```